# Expression in annotation using fields of class in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-el

I use method level security. In class I annotated some methods, expressions use fields of this class. But I see SpEL exceptions, that I can't reference them.
Here is part of code of this class. In expressions I want to use field repPrefix, but I receive exceptions that it's an unknown variable.

```
@Component("c2rTableManager")
@Scope("prototype")
public class C2RTableManager implements TableManager {
     private final TableManager tableManager;
     private final String repPrefix;

     @Autowired
     private SecurityInfoService securityInfoService;

     public C2RTableManager(TableManager tableManager, String repository) {
          this.tableManager = tableManager;
          this.repPrefix = repository + "__";
     }

     ...some methods

     @Override
     @PreAuthorize("hasRole('DBA') || hasPermission(repPrefix + #table, 'TABLE', 'DELETE_TABLE')")
     public void dropTable(String table) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
          tableManager.dropTable(table);
     }

     ...other methods
}
```

If I write another way, expressions AREN'T EVALUATED at all. Can't understand why.

```
@Component("c2rTableManager")
@Scope("prototype")
public class C2RTableManager implements TableManager {
     private final TableManager tableManager;
     private final String repPrefix;

     @Autowired
     private SecurityInfoService securityInfoService;

     public C2RTableManager(TableManager tableManager, String repository) {
          this.tableManager = tableManager;
          this.repPrefix = repository + "__";
     }

     ...some methods

     @Override

     public void dropTable(String table) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
          dropTable(table, repPrefix);
     }

     @PreAuthorize("hasRole('DBA') || hasPermission(#repPrefix + #table, 'TABLE', 'DELETE_TABLE')")
     public void dropTable(String table, String repPrefix) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
          tableManager.dropTable(table);
     }

     ...other methods
}
```

How can I write expressions for methods of class using values of fields of this class?

Comment: what is the exact: SPEL exception?

Comment: something like unknown variable, can't evaluate it and etc.

Comment: If you use interface AOP proxies, a method invocation from the same instance will not evaluate any annotations.

Comment: I don't know anything about AOP. But is im possible to make method invocation from the same instance evaluate annotations? If i clone instance and call required method, will it be OK? `this.clone().dropTable(table, repPrefix);`

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation for adding a comment.
From the Spring Security docs available at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

> Here we're actually using a method argument as part of the expression
>   to decide whether the current user has the “admin”permission for the
>   given contact. The built-in hasPermission() expression is linked into
>   the Spring Security ACL module through the application context, as
>   we'll see below. You can access any of the method arguments by name as
>   expression variables, provided your code has debug information
>   compiled in.

Please stress on the Last sentence. Check the below two points:

- Did you Compile the classes with debug flag on?
- Did you enable the method level security with this declaration:`<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>`

Comment: I don't know aboub compilation with debug, because I build applications with Maven and debug them in NetBeans. Of course this declaration is enabled, other experssions work normally.But why some expressions are evaluated (1st example), but some are not (2nd example)?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to declare bield as public

```
private final String repPrefix;
```

And write annotation with link to this

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('DBA') || hasPermission(repPrefix + #table, 'TABLE', 'DELETE_TABLE')")
```